# Jupiter theme Mega menu option not available

Tags: menus

I am using WordPress

> Jupiter theme version 1.0

Wordpress version is

> 4.7.15

Mega menu option was enabled for some menu items and it was working perfectly for years.
But suddenly from several weeks ago, mega menu was disappeared. Even the checkbox to enable that feature also not available.
As a quick fix, I restored a several weeks old backup.
The restored site had the mega menu, but after several hours it was gone again.
What may be the reason for this behaviour?
How can I get mega menu back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally, I found the reason and the solution myself.
The issue occurred due to a conflict of plugins. The latest popup maker plugin makes the mega menu checkbox invisible.

To get back the checkbox in the menu, follow these steps.

Popup Maker > Settings > Misc :

**Disable Popups Menu Editor**  (Use this if there is a conflict with your theme or another plugin in the nav menu editor.)